# Pygtk installation error and printmaster

Tags: python, pygtk

I a trying to download and install Pygtk in windowns (Python 2.6). When I download the installation file (http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.1.win32-py2.6.msi.sig), I get a broderbund printmaster registration form that I tried to avoid as much as possible. Among other things it asked when I bought the product. Do I need to buy this product??? Anyway, my installation of Pygtk fails because the printmaster cannot find a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some url as following:

```
http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/binaries/win32/pygtk/2.24/pygtk-all-in-one-2.24.1.win32-py2.6.msi
```

to download the correct installer of pygtk. The file ended with `.sig` is only a digital signature to check if the target package you downloaded is corrupt or not.